# Multilingual Publishing Pack (MLP): make a link to the corresponding page in the another language?

Tags: multilingual, internationalization, language

I am helping to build a bilingual website using MLP on TextPattern. It's trivial to put a link to the top level page of another language, but how to put a link to the current page in another language?

Eg. `/en/contact` should link to `/de/kontakt` (the same article in another language).

I'm sure there are some variables somewhere that I could put into the template that would be filled with the correct links.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<txp:l10n_lang_list />` tag.

According to the plugin help documentation:

> On an article list page, this outputs all of the site’s available languages. On individual articles it lists only those languages the article has renditions for.

Remember that section names for URLs aren't translatable by the MLP. So `/en/contact` will link to `/de/contact`.  On the other hand, URLs for articles are translatable.